# pipe causing processes to freeze

Tags: c, pipe

The program `report` launches two `accessed` processes. Report basically feeds `accessed` a list of filenames and `accessed` prints if they have been accessed in x days.

However, my implementation is causing `accessed` to freeze somehow. After running `reports`, nothing gets printed. When I run `ps`, I can see two `accessed` programs hanging around, not dying.

At first, I thought the method of reading from stdin was wrong in `accessed`, but I manually piped some filenames to it `cat filenames.txt | ./accessed`, and it works. So `report` program must be wrong.

I attached gdb to the frozen `accessed` processes and it seems that it is frozen at the while loop `getline`. So I changed the while loop to a single `getline` statement and it suddenly works. However, I need to read `stdin` until EOF. Any help on the possible sources of errors is very much appreciated. This is causing me much headache.

Schematics:

```
--------
|      |--------> Access1  ---> print stuff out
|report|
|______|--------> Access2 ----> print stuff out
```

Comment: How many processes have the pipe open? It looks like A1 has both ends of `pipe_RtoA2` open, and A2 has both ends of `pipe_RtoA1` open. So it will never read EOF, because (as far as the system knows) one of the accessed processes might send data to the other.

Comment: Am I suppose to close the unneeded pipes in the children? Sorry if its a stupid question, I am still learning about ipc.

Comment: Children inherit open file descriptors - so if you have a file descriptor you don't want the child process to inherit, then the child process should close it.

Comment: Yep, that was the problem!

Comment: Can you post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each process closes its own input pipe (after dup2'ing the read end).

However, they leave the *other process's* input pipe open. Each one will never see an EOF, even after the parent process closes it, since there's the possibility that the other child process might decide to send data to it.

The children should close each others' pipes (or be started without inheriting the other process's pipes).